# PHP SQL mssql_bind with XML

Tags: php, sql-server, xml

How does one sent XML into a stored procedure from PHP?
I've tried several different datatypes in PHP.

Here is the PHP:

```
$model_look_xml = '<root><id>7</id><id>6</id><id>12</id></root>';
$query = mssql_init("AdvMS"); 

mssql_bind($query,"@model_look_xml",$model_look_xml,SQLVARCHAR,  false,  false,  200);

$result = mssql_execute($query);
```

The original SP had @model_look_xml xml, it worked fine on it's own.  Just not binding with php.  The remaining SP binded fine, just not the XML

I have also tried casting a string inside SQL to XML.
Which didn't work inside the SP:

```
@model_look_xml varchar(200),
DECLARE @model_look_xml1 xml
set @model_look_xml1 = CAST(@model_look_xml AS XML)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

PHP side:

```
mssql_bind($query,"@model_look_xml",$model_look_xml,SQLVARCHAR,  false,  false,  200);
```

SQL side:

```
 @model_look_xml xml,
```

What fixed the problem was missing this:

```
SET ANSI_PADDING ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
set CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;
```